# Handl unique key error on specific column

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to catch the Unique Key Error on a specific column.

Let's say there is a table with 3 columns `(id, name, value)`.

All 3 columns are unique (not composite).

When I make an insert and fails, I want to retry the insert, but only if it is because of the `value` column.

E.g. If inserting because of the `value` columns failed, I want to retry the inserting, but if it is because of the `name` column, I do not want to retry the inserting.

How can I know in which column the error has occurred?

What I have found so far is to use the error code, but this does not give me in which column the Unique Error has occurred.

```
try {
   $foo = new Foo(['foo' => 42, 'bar' => 1]);
   $foo->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) { // It's actually a QueryException but this works too
   if ($e->getCode() == 23000) {
       // Deal with duplicate key error  
   }
}
```

Should I use regex to analyze the message or is there a better way?

Comment: what about creating custom validation before inserting ?

Comment: @JohnLobo You mean to check if the value exists or not?

Comment: Did you look at the error message `$e->getMessage()` Its feels clumsy but it may be what you need

Comment: Yes, I did, then I have to work with Regex to detect the specific column.

Comment: @Rans.exactly you sre right.thats the easiest way to handle as per my knowlege